# How to enable full layout touch keyboard on Windows 10 1709?

Tags: windows-10-v1709, touch-keyboard

Windows 10 1709 comes with an unpleasant surprise: the "new" touch keyboard doesn't have the "Full Layout" option (which gives you all keys you expect in a keyboard like arrows and DEL) anymore. (Yeah! Thanks, Microsoft...)

How could someone bring the old keyboard back? It surely must have a registry key hidden for it.

P.s. I know the old keyboard still exists because it shows in my lock screen (with the full layout)

[This](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/full-layout-touch-keyboard-windows-10) is how you enable it in 1703 and previous versions. This option DOES NOT EXIST ANYMORE in 1709.

This is what the keyboard "options" button shows me:

[image]

Comment: How did you think I *enabled* it in the first place? ;)

Comment: I believe we are not in the same page here. If you know the answer, please be kind and POST IT in a clear and concise way. I already explained how I enabled the setting in the old Windows version. The "options" button you are referring to (I presume) doesn't have anything to change the keyboard layout (I updated the question with a screenshot of it).

Comment: Based on what I can tell you have not enabled the full keyboard layout in the Settings application.  If the Settings application no longer has that option submit a screenshot of that.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/the-windows-10-touch-keyboard-is-not-using-the/1ef577d7-1b99-470e-8fb4-d930e22fbc61?auth=1 If the option is missing chnage your keyboard layout to a supported region

Comment: Oh man... Thanks @Ramhound! You nailed! (Please post it as an answer). Anyway, this doesn't solve the problem. Older version of Windows had the full keyboard working for any region/language. In 1709 it appears to work only in US. If they don't call this a "regression" I don't know what is. :)

Comment: You can try removing then install the keyboard layout/language pack again and see if that helps.  It also might be a bug so I suggest you provided your feedback through the appropriate channels.

Comment: @Typist indeed we weren't on the same page, the OnScreen keyboard looks a bit different and does have an actual button labeled "Options", my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Until Microsoft solves this, I replaced my tabtip files with the older files from the `Windows.old` directory. I've copied the following directories:

`C:\Windows.old\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink`
to -> `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink`
and
`C:\Windows.old\‏‏Program Files (x86)‎\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink`
to ->  `C:\‏‏Program Files (x86)‎\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink`

that brings back the older touch keyboard from build 1703 with the full keyboard layout for non-English region layouts.

I copied the directories using command prompt from Windows 
recovery since the files are in use in normal Windows boot.