# Touch Keyboard on Windows 10 Logon Screen

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, kiosk

We are using Windows 10 on a kiosk system. Normally, the user interacts with the system via touch-screen, but a keyboard is available if required.

We have enabled "Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device." in the typing settings [image: Settings] and during normal operation, this is what we require.
Whenever the user uses the touch input to focus control that accepts text, the touch keyboard is shown. If he uses mouse or keyboard, it stays hidden.

However, on the Login or Lock Screen, no keyboard is shown. A worse one may be manually shown using the Ease of Access settings, but this is not something that the user should need to do on every login. Can we get the same behaviour at the Login Screen as later in the OS?

Comment: Questions: (1) Is Windows fully updated? (2) Are you on Tablet mode? (3) Does this behavior persist if you reboot the device? (4) Did this always happen or only began after a Windows update ([interesting link](https://superuser.com/questions/1260149/how-to-enable-full-layout-touch-keyboard-on-windows-10-1709))?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/954803/windows-10-lock-screen-no-keyboard

Comment: Why do you post a bounty if you don't respond to comments & answers ?

Comment: @harrymc Good question, I've always wondered that myself on those type of bounty questions. One somewhat slight commonality I've noticed with this regard (not every time though) is it's with members of communities when they have much higher rep in other SE communities so my guess would be they come here to ask question, it doesn't get attention, they bounty it eventually and then likely forget about it. I've had to go to the community they're a member of with the much higher rep and ping them about it there with a link back before which has worked for me a time or two.

Comment: ^^^ I know I'm not telling you anything you don't already know tho but my little two cents on the topic for my short time here on the SU community.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: Interesting info. I always wondered if there wasn't anything SU could do about it, but starting a discussion about the subject on Meta probably won't come up with any agreed results.

Comment: @harrymc:I am currently ill and not working on this problem for now. Talk about bad timing, sorry.

Comment: Windows is fully updated. I am not on tablet mode. I will check if this could be done for our kind of application as soon as I am back in the office.

Comment: For now, it happens every time, but we have not tried to do this on a much earlier update.

Comment: Feel well - thank you for making the effort.

Comment: Use regedit to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk`. Check if `CopySettingsToLockedDesktop` is set to 1. Tablet mode should be set before.

Answer (score 1):

Having the keyboard attached will change the behavior of Windows. Unplug the keyboard and reboot.

Alternatively you can try this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We might use this if no other option materializes itself. We've found the on-screen-keyboard to have a far worse user experience than the touch keyboard, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the tips listed, you can also enable Tablet Mode.  This will bring the on-screen keyboard each time input is needed.

To enable Tablet Mode, open the Notification bar (Win + A) and then click on Tablet Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following checkbox:
`Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Change sign-in settings [on the left] -> Type without keyboard (On-Screen Keyboard) : at sign-in`.

[image]

[source](https://www.techbout.com/enable-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-10-30286/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Set Tablet mode
- Use regedit to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\osk`
- Check if `CopySettingsToLockedDesktop` is set to 1, and set it if not
- Reboot

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 has so many bugs. 
Sometimes,we have to find a third party software solution.
For your situation, I recommend a software named 'Tabtip on-demand',
a good software developed by a Swiss developer. 
Here's an overview from their own site:

> Tabtip On-Demand is a great tool for mobile users with Tablet PC which adds the missing keyboard « on-demand » functionality to the WIndows input panel. It is also able to scroll web pages and push input fields into view, thus the text are typing is never hidden behind the keyboard. Tabtip On-Demand also makes the keyboard available by mouse click (optional) on the desktop as well as in the Modern UI (Windows 8 and above).

This is what Tabtip looks like:
[image]

I'm using it now to type this answer.

Personally, I think it is useful; you can forget it once you start it. 
You can always make setting by clicking its icon at right menu corner. 
It has two modes: Tabtip mode and OSK mode. 
However, it cannot always pop up in some special text field
(for example,text field of Google), then you have to start keyboard manually.

P.S. It costs only $2, a cheap choice.

Here is its official Website. 
May it help you :) 
http://www.chessware.ch/tabtipod